# Storing $_SESSION variable after multiple submits

Tags: php, forms, session

I have a form with multiple submissions. First there is a drop down menu with a few selections. Based on that selection, some language changes on the page (Buck instead of Bull...etc.) When a value from the menu is selected more form inputs are displayed. After the user fills out the rest and submits that data then it is written to a database. The issue I am having is I am trying to use $_SESSION to store the first $_POST value.

It will store it after the first post, but after the second it gets cleared. Very frustrating.

```
<?
include_once('global_inc.php');//required for debugging
include_once('MySQL.php');//connects this form to the database
session_start();
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="<?php print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post" id="cervidSolutions">
<?
if (empty($_POST)) {
  echo "<h3>Please select the species of your farm.</h3>";
  echo "<select name='cervid'>";

  $list = array("WHITETAIL"=>"Whitetail", "RED_DEER"=>"Red Deer", "ELK"=>"Elk", "FALLOW_DEER"=>"Fallow Deer", "MULE_DEER"=>"Mule Deer");

  foreach ($list as $key=>$value) { //Creates a drop down from the above array
    echo "<option value='{$key}'";

    if ($_POST['cervid'] == $key) 
      echo " selected";

    echo ">{$value}</option>";
  }
  echo "</select>";
  echo "<input type='submit' name='speciesSelected' value='Select Species' />";
}

$_SESSION['cervid'] = $_POST['cervid'];

//Statements to assign noun values
if ($_POST['cervid'] == "WHITETAIL" || $_POST['cervid'] == "MULE_DEER" || $_POST['cervid'] == "FALLOW_DEER") {
  $maleNames = "Buck";
  $femaleNames = "Doe";
  $babyNames = "Fawn";
} else {
  $maleNames = "Bull";
  $femaleNames = "Hind";
  $babyNames = "Calf";
}

 /* Main form information including name, email, phone number and head count. */
if (!empty($_POST['cervid'])) { //These elements will only appear if $_POST['cervid'] has a value

echo "<p>Please type your name, email, and phone number. This information will help us provide you with any assistence you may need.</p>
<fieldset class='mainFormNamesFieldset'>
    <label for='firstName'>First Name</label>
    <input type='text' value='' name='firstName' class='mainFormNames' required />
</fieldset>
<fieldset class='mainFormNamesFieldset'>
    <label for='lastName'>Last Name</label>
    <input type='text' value='' name='lastName' class='mainFormNames' required />
</fieldset>
<fieldset class='mainFormEmailFieldset'>
    <label for='emailAddress'>Email Address</label>
    <input type='email' value='' name='emailAddress' class='mainFormEmail' required />
</fieldset>
<fieldset class='mainFormPhoneFieldset'>
    <label for='phoneNumber'>Phone Number</label>
    <div class='phoneWrap'>
    <input type='text' value='' maxlength='3' name='phoneNumber1' id='mainFormPhoneFirst' required /><span class='dash'>-</span>
    <input type='text' value='' maxlength='3' name='phoneNumber2' id='mainFormPhoneMiddle' required /><span class='dash'>-</span>
    <input type='text' value='' maxlength='4' name='phoneNumber3' id='mainFormPhoneLast' required />        
    </div>
    <div class='phoneWrap'>
    <span id='hashLeft'>###</span>
    <span id='hashMiddle'>###</span>
    <span id='hashRight'>####</span>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class='mainFormHerdFieldset'>
    <label for='maleHeadCount'>Number of ". $maleNames ."</label>
    <input type='text' value='' maxlength='3' size='3' name='maleHeadCount' class='mainFormMale' />
</fieldset>
<fieldset class='mainFormHerdFieldset'>
    <label for='femaleHeadCount'>Number of ". $femaleNames ."</label>
    <input type='text' value='' maxlength='3' size='3' name='femaleHeadCount' class='mainFormFemale' />
</fieldset>
<fieldset class='mainFormHerdFieldset'>
    <label for='femaleHeadCount'>Number of ". $babyNames ."</label>
    <input type='text' value='' maxlength='3' size='3' name='babyHeadCount' class='mainFormBaby' />
</fieldset>
<input type='submit' name='custInfo' value='Submit Data' id='submitCustInfo' /><input type='reset' name='reset' value='Reset Form' id='resetForm' />";
}
```

That is all the relevant code. The rest is just some variable calculations and an insert statement. I know the insert statement is correct because if I hardcode a value it will write it. Doing a print_r($_SESSION['cervid']); displays the variable after the first post, but it clears after the second.

Answer (score 0):

While your approach is less than ideal, I believe you can "fix" your current problem by changing this line:

```
$_SESSION['cervid'] = $_POST['cervid'];
```

to this:

```
if(isset($_POST['cervid']))
  $_SESSION['cervid'] = $_POST['cervid'];
```

Comment: I have tried that previously and it still will not keep $_SESSION between submits.

Comment: The difference between my version and yours is that the session variable is only set if that value is present in the posted array of data. According to the code you posted, the 'cervid select dropdown' will only print if there is no posted data. On the initial page load, the select dropdown is on the page. On the first form submission the session variable is set and the outputted page no longer contains the select dropdown, therefore it will not be set on subsequent page loads as long as they are triggered by posted form submissions. What are we missing here?